# React class instance prop prevents from using PureComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, reselect

My React component has a prop that is a class instance based from data coming from the redux store.

The reason for this is that it is much more convenient to deal with this data using a class and all its custom methods (more than 50).

I cannot use PureComponent as React always consider that this prop has changed. The problem is that most of my React components are connected to this prop...

I am aware of solution like reselect but this would mean having too many (as many as my class has custom methods) selectors only for the manipulation of this data.

What would you suggest?

My redux select looks like this:

```
getStation(state) {
  // some logic to fetch the right station
  return new WeatherStation(state.services.stationList[i])
}
```

where WeatherStation is:

```
class WeatherStation {
  constructor (data) {
    this.station = data
  }

  getId() {...}
  // many more methods
}
```

and within my React Compoonent:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      station: getStation(state),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Have you tried ImmutableJS?

Comment: Would also like to see the code. Especially where you create your class instance.

Comment: You need to provide us with a [mcve] so we can help you more easily. Are you creating a new instance of the class every time that something is updated? @hawk how would using ImmutableJS help?

Comment: Indeed a new instance is created each time in the selector

Comment: @TomFenech To use PureComponent you need immutable data for `shallowCompare` to properly work.. so every time you change your data result will be new data, immutablejs provide all this + smart compairison algorithms

Comment: OK, but the OP is talking about a prop which is a class - it sounds like they would need to completely change this in order for ImmutableJS to be an option.

Comment: @VincentToupet Have you had time to try my suggestion? Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `reselect` along these lines?

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

getStationData(state) {
  // some logic to fetch the right station

  // no new instances here, just selecting the relevant data
  return state.services.stationList[i];
}


// create "memoized" selector. 
const getEnhancedStation = createSelector(
  getStationData,
  stationData => new WeatherStation(stationData)
)
```

If I understand `reselect` and [`createSelector`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#creating-a-memoized-selector) correctly, then this should generate a new WeatherStation instance **only if** the underlying data, ie. the thing returned from `getStationData`,  has changed. (Instead of generating a new instance each time *anything* in the state  changes.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonahe, it works like a charm. This will help me remove lots of unnecessary code from shouldComponentUpdate methods of my components